# Is the maximum CF capacity supported by EOS-1Ds really 8 GB?

Tags: canon, compactflash

I'm looking for the maximum supported CF capacity for the EOS-1Ds with firmware 1.0.3. dpreview simply [states "FAT32 (over 2 GB)"](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canoneos1ds/2). Looking around the net there are different statements, both indicating max 8 GB if formatted in the camera and as a hard maximum, but also that 16 and 32 GB has been used successfully[[2]](http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/topic/852582),[[3]](http://photo.net/canon-eos-digital-camera-forum/00XT8j).

The sources from Canon that I've read are outdated and does not even discuss the maximum capacity.

I can't see why it wouldn't support larger cards than 8 GB if it's formatted with FAT32 which enables larger capacities than 2 GB. Has anyone used a larger card and filled it past 8 GB or knows the actual limit of the camera?

Comment: Why not just put a larger card in and try it? The worst thing that can happen is that the camera will not recognize the card.

Comment: @MichaelClark I don't have the camera. I've just found a good deal. I don't want to invest in old overpriced cards if my larger ones won't fit. If someone here has some first hand knowledge it would be great.

Comment: This answer may help. I've seen several reports that formatting the card and creating the correct file structure using a computer will enable use of the full capacity of a card of greater than 8GB capacity when used in cameras with firmware that will only recognize 8GB of the card's capacity if formatted in-camera. http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45356/15871

Comment: If you place a card with greater than 8GB capacity into one of the cameras with an 8GB limit and format it in camera, the camera will only format and use 8GB of the card's capacity.

Comment: Or maybe not. http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/42438523

Comment: Note that the problems in the dpreview link above occurred with the old FAT16 firmware and cards pre-formatted using FAT32. The problem seems to have been the cards balked at being formatted to FAT16 by the camera.

Comment: @MichaelClark Ok, I probably will buy the camera soon, try it out and report back again here as soon as I know how it handles the larger cards then.

Comment: I think the key is to not format them in the 1Ds. If you do that the camera will create an 8GB partition and only use that. You may or may not be able to use partitioning tools on a computer to restore the rest of the card to one partition. So instead of the 1Ds use a newer Canon camera or your PC. If the last paragraph in the following link doesn't work, then use the PC to create a '100CANON' folder inside the 'DCIM' folder and see if that works. http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45356/15871

Comment: And if the camera's firmware has not been updated to v.1.0.3 you will either need one 2GB FAT16 (or smaller) card or create a 2GB FAT16 root partition on a larger card to install the updated firmware.

Comment: @MichaelClark I know, I'll have to do that to. Since it's such an old camera I don't want anything to get wrong so I'll see if I can borrow a smaller card just for the update.

Comment: It might be related to a cluster size that a camera can read. If 8GB is a limit than it means that maximum cluster size that can be read by build-in card controller is 4KB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a Canon EOS 1Ds mark 1, and I have recently put in a 32GB card. It is true that in-camera formatting only allows for an 8 GB partition to be created.
However, if I re-partition the card on my computer and create a 32 GB partition, the camera will recognize all 32 GB.

I have tested filling the card beyond 8 GB, and it still seems to work in the camera.

So conclusion, it works, but only if you format on a computer :)